AWS ECS Task using Iptables
I have an AWS ECS Task with 2 containers: A Golang application and an Envoy proxy. The flow should be something like this:
Go --> GET site.com --> Envoy proxy intercepts it --> GET newsite.com
So, in the end, I would like to redirect the Golang app to the newsite.com.
I can achieve it on Kubernetes using Iptables, like this:
Go --> GET site.com --> Iptables PREROUTING to Envoy proxy --> Envoy proxy intercepts it --> GET newsite.com
So in Kubernetes, it acts as a transparent proxy, but I don't know how to achieve the same behavior on AWS ECS (Fargate and EC2).

I'm not aware of any ECS specific solution for capturing outbound traffic, only inbound traffic.  I think you would just have to configure iptables inside the docker image that has your Go application. Also, the terms "redirect" and "proxy" refer to two completely different concepts. You are only doing a proxy here, not a redirect. A redirect is when a server responds, telling you to make another network connection to a completely different server, which is not what you are trying to achieve.

so do you think if I apply iptables on my sidecar it will reflect on Go app too since they way on the same task ?

No, it would have to be done inside the Go app container, as I said.
